# Fundamental theorem of algebra with polynomial division

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

We start by proving: We call $x^n =1$ the $n$-th unity root, Show that when $z^n-1$  is factorized into $(z^n-1)=(z-a_1)...(z-a_n)$ show that $x$ is the $n$-th unity root when $x = a_i$ for some $1\le i <n$

This was done with $0=x^n-1=(x-a_1)...(x-a_n) $ so at least one $(x-a_i)$ has to be zero so $a_i=x$.

Then I showed $(z^n-1):(z-x)=\sum^{m-1}_{i=0} z^ix^{(n-1)-i}$ with polynomial devision. (Does this really imply that all $a_i$ are unity roots? Did I miss a step?
My Textbook says proving this is the same as proving $(z^nx^{n-m}-1):(z-x)=\sum^{m-1}_{i=0} z^ix^{(n-1)-i}$ with $m=1,2,..,n$ by induction. I don't think I understood this correct. In which way relates the polynomial $\sum^{m-1}_{i=0}$ to $(z^nx^{n-m}-1)$

Now I have to show that every $a_i$ from $(z^n-1)=(z-a_1)...(z-a_n)$ is different from some other $a_j$ with $1\le j <n$

Comment: That's false: if $x=1$, you *can* divide.

Comment: How can i show then that every $a_i$ is different?

Comment: Different from what?

Comment: From some other $a_k$ with $1<k\le n$

Comment: The polynomial $x^n-1$ has all roots distinct since it has no common roots with its derivative $nx^{n-1}$.

Comment: Then if i showed that every $a_i$ is a $i$th unit root this implies that no $a_i$ has the same value as another?

Comment: Being an $i$-th root of unity is not the reason why they're all dfferent. It's linked to the fact that a multiple toot (when one $a_i$ is the same as another) is also a root of the derivative. Now here, the derivative has only one root, $0$, which is not a root of $x^n-1$. Furthermore, the roots are known: they're the $\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2ik\pi}n}$s, for $k=0,1,\dots, n-1$.

Comment: Is there a way of describing it without using the derivative? This and terms like $\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2ik\pi}n}$ we did not cover in class, so I think I won't be allowed to do this. Will edit my question in a moment with every step of the proof

Comment: It's not very hard to show that $x^n-1$ is divisible by $(x-x_i)^2$, then $x_i$ is a root of the derivative: just compute the derivative of $(x-x_i)^2q(x)$ and its value for $x=x_i$.

Comment: I tried to divide $x^n-1$ with $(x^2-2xx_i+x_i^2)$ but ended up with a remainder of $2xx_i^{n-1}-1$ on the last step. Where did i go wrong?

Comment: You didn't go wrong. That's normal, since $x_i$ is *never* a double root, so the remainder can't be $0$.